# Meaning of List<HashMap<String, String>> nearbyPlacesList

Tags: java, android

I would like if someone could explain me what is the meaning of this in java 
`List<HashMap<String, String>> nearbyPlacesList`

Comment: A sequence of String -> String maps

Comment: What about it confuses you? Do you know what a List is? A HashMap? Do you understand generics?

Comment: @Mark, when I asked here is because I have some doubts, to your first question, what confused me was HashMap<String, String>, to your second question, yes I know what a list is, to your third question, no I didn't knew until now what a Hasmap was(thats why I asked on first place in case you didn't red my question), and to your 4th question, I know some generics, thanks for for your answer

Comment: I did read your question. It does in fact not specify that you don't know what a HashMap is. You ask about a list of hashmaps. There are a lot of things about that which might confuse you and there is no way to know which part of that you don't understand without clarification. which is why I asked these questions ;). Also, you should double check if the word "doubt" is really what you mean here. You did get some answers anyway that explain it, but just keep those things in mind for your next question.

Comment: Thanks for your explanation my friend, please, if you are one of those who downvoted let me know what to fix here

Comment: @JuanAntonioSánchezJiménez: please don't edit the question to change what it asks. Especially if you've already gotten answers and even marked them as accepted, as that makes the answers "wrong".

Comment: @JoachimSauer I am sorry is just that my question has been downvoted and I would like to recover my points, sorry for the troubles :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That means that you have a `List` containing instances of `HashMap`s that takes `String` data as both keys and values.

Oh, and the variable is called `nearbyPlacesList`.

Answer (score 0):

It's a `List` which contains `HashMap` elements with a key of `String` type and a value of `String` type.

Answer (score 0):

It is a `List` consisting of possibly multiple `HashMap`'s where the key-value are `String`s.

e.g.

```
nearbyPlacesList.get(0); // returns first HashMap in the List
nearbyPlacesList.get(0).get("park"); // returns value of the first Map which has the key park
```

and so on.

Answer (score 0):

A HashMap contains key-value pairs of different kinds (in your case String).

Let's take an example right here. A store. In a store there can be different clothes.

```
HashMap<String, String> tShirts;
HashMap<String, String> jeans;
```

where the key-value pair could be for example "Price" and "100€", and they can all be stored in the following list containing different clothes:

```
List<HashMap<String, String>> clothes;
clothes.add(tShirts);
clothes.add(jeans);
```

Answer (score 0):

The first piece of information that we see is a list, so we know it's a list. Then we see it is a hashmap (take a look here at the java docs if you are not familiar https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/HashMap.html)

So it's a list of hashmaps, with two strings as the key value pair.

Answer (score 0):

```
HashMap<String,String>
```

It uses to store your data as a **key** and **value** pair.

When There is  more than one HashMap you want to store. you can store all hashmaps into a single list like this.

```
List<HashMap<String,String>>
```